# How would I keep totalCalc from resetting?

Tags: c, function

I am making a program to calculate the most efficient amount of change to give when the user inputs a certain dollar value.

The program worked before I tried to make it into functions, and when I tried to make my program more robust by using functions, the program isn't working as desired.

```
double getValueofCoins(int totalCalc, int coinValue, char* coinName) {

    double coinType;

    coinType = totalCalc / coinValue;
    totalCalc = totalCalc % coinValue; 
    printf("\n%s: %.0lf", coinName, coinType);

    return totalCalc;

}



int makeChange(int totalCalc) {

    double total;

    // calculate the most efficient amount of change

    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 200, "Toonies");
    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 100, "Loonies");
    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 25, "Quarters");
    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 10, "Dimes");
    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 5, "Nickels");
    getValueofCoins(totalCalc, 1, "Pennies");

    return total;    
}
```

What I want the code to do is give the most efficient amount of change (eg: if the user enters $20, it would say 10 toonies), but what it does is print the amount of each type of coin that would make up the value (eg: if the user enters $20, it would say 10 toonies, 20 loonies, 80 quarters, etc.)

I think this is because the totalCalc variable is resetting to what the user inputted originally every time I call getValueofCoins(). How would I fix this?

Comment: You need to assign the return value to the variable. Now you’re changing it and returning it from the function but the return value is not used anywhere.

Comment: Please consider to expand your code to a [MCVE]. Also in `makeChange` you return `total` which is a `double`, but the return type of `makeChange` is `int`.

Comment: Please show both versions, each as an MCVE, the working one before and the failing one after using functions.